Does one prophet ever prophesize to another in Tanach?
In 1 Kings 13 a prophet, whom Hazal identify as Iddo, receives a prophecy from another prophet. Are there any other times in Tanach where two people are identified in the text as being prophets where one prophet prophesizes to the other?

When Nathan rebukes David

This week's parsha דַּבֵּ֥ר אֶֽל־אַהֲרֹ֖ן לֵאמֹ֑ר אִ֣ישׁ מִֽזַּרְעֲךָ֞ לְדֹרֹתָ֗ם אֲשֶׁ֨ר יִהְיֶ֥ה בוֹ֙ מ֔וּם לֹ֣א יִקְרַ֔ב לְהַקְרִ֖יב לֶ֥חֶם אֱלֹהָֽיו

@ClintEastwood David is not described in Tanach as a prophet.

@DoubleAA is Aaron ever called a prophet in Tanach?

How about Samuel rebuking Saul? Shaul is definitely described as a prophet in I Samuel, chapter 10

@rikitikitembo Yes וְאַהֲרֹן אָחִיךָ יִהְיֶה נְבִיאֶךָ and אִם־יִֽהְיֶה֙ נְבִ֣יאֲכֶ֔ם but more importantly, did God just talk to Moshe the whole time? הֲרַ֤ק אַךְ־בְּמֹשֶׁה֙ דִּבֶּ֣ר יְהוָ֔ה הֲלֹ֖א גַּם־בָּ֣נוּ דִבֵּ֑ר God talks to Aharon directly multiple times וַיְדַבֵּר יְהוָה, אֶל-אַהֲרֹן לֵאמֹר. יַיִן וְשֵׁכָר אַל-תֵּשְׁתְּ

To strengthen the question: Are there occasions where one prophet prophesizes to another prophet, thereby contradicting the original prophet's prophecy? Why did Iddo trust that the other (false) prophet's prophecy superseded his own prophecy?

A man of Elokim gives a prophecy to Eli in Shmuel 1:2:27. Shmuel gives one to Eli in ibid 1:3:18. If you consider Chana to be a prophetess, then Eli gives her a prophecy in ibid 1:1:17

@RabbiKaii where does it say Eli is a prophet?

In Jeremiah chapter 28 Jeremiah the prophet prophesizes to Hananiah the prophet (and vise versa).

B"H
Shmuel 2:27
A man or G-d, clearly a prophet (see commentaries) came to tell Eli (also a prophet) a message from Hashem

וַיָּבֹא אִישׁ אֱלֹהִים, נביא אֶל עֵלִי, וַיֹּאמֶר אֵלָיו: כֹּה אָמַר
ה': הֲנִגְלֹה, הלוא נִגְלֵיתִי אֶל בֵּית אָבִיךָ בִּהְיוֹתָם
בְּמִצְרַיִם נתונים לְבֵית פַּרְעֹה,
A man of God, a prophet, came to Eli, and he said to him: So said the
Lord: Did I not appear to your father’s house, when they were in Egypt
under the house of Pharaoh?


how do you know Eli is a prophet?

@rikitikitembo commentaries

@rikitikitembo I will answer your similar comment to me, here. According to one opinion he prophesises to Chana in 1:1:17. That opinion (e.g. Radak) states "because he was a prophet". He was the head of the court of the tranmission of the Oral Torah too, and it was initially passed through the prophets. It's not controversial that he was a prophet. Even if not, doesn't DoubleAA's answer in the comments above provide a slam dunk?

no, the question specifically asks for people whom the pesukim refer to as prophets/neviim. The comment  you reference does not show Aaron as being referred to as a Navi except once where the word clearly doesn't mean prophet unless we also assume Moshe is God.

@RabbiKaii to clarify, not everyone who hears the word of God is deemed a prophet. A prophet has unique halachik status etc.

@rikitiki not once twice, and the second time does mean Prophecy

@rikitikitembo I admit the Tanach doesn't say it, apologies for missing that so I understand why you don't accept it as a valid answer. Eli is not a case of "not a prophet even though.." -  he is definitely a prophet, according to Chazal

@rikitikitembo it says in the tanach (Torah) not to stray from the matter that they tell you right or left. And the chazal, that the Torah tells us to listen to, clearly say he is a prophet

@Awtsmoos--עצמות I'm not here to debate that. the question is clear about asking for examples based on what is explicit in the text only, therefore this answer would not qualify.

@rikitikitembo NOTHING is explicit in the text only. The written Torah is impossible to understand without it's explanation.

@Awtsmoos--עצמות I don't know about that, there's another answer that is based on what is explicit in the text. If you disagree with the framing of the question I would suggest not answering rather than leaving an answer that doesn't comply with the criteria of the question

@rikitikitembo question just says "in the text". What text? Chazal statements from the midrash etc are text as well

the antecedent is the word Tanach

@rikitikitembo and the tanach is only understood with chazal

assumes facts not in evidence
